# Query to fetch multiple time range data in single query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, azure-synapse, azure-synapse-analytics

I have a table named Order which have transaction related information like

- order_id
- customer_id
- net_amount
- net_discount
- order_date

I want to fetch the details of a customer over different time periods through a single line result.

ex. If I need the total amount spend and total discount availed data for lifetime by each customer then I can query

```
SELECT customer_id,
       sum(net_amount)   AS total_spent,
       sum(net_discount) AS total_discount
FROM   Order
GROUP  BY customer_id;
```

Similarly if I need for last 10 days then I can write

```
SELECT   customer_id,
         SUM(net_amount)   AS total_spent,
         SUM(net_discount) AS total_discount
FROM     ORDER
GROUP BY customer_id
WHERE    order_date BETWEEN FORMAT(GETDATE(), 'yyyy-MM-dd') AND FORMAT(DATEADD(dd,-10,GETDATE()), 'yyyy-MM-dd');
```

In the above example I have to write 2 separate queries and get results separately.

My requirement is how can I fetch the the values in single line grouping by customer ID i.e. I should get the lifetime spend, last 10 days spend, last 30 days spend in a single row for different time ranges for each customer.

Comment: Please show sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below query worked for me in dedicated SQL Pool. Thanks to @martin for the original response.

```
SELECT customer_id,
       SUM(net_amount)   AS total_spent,
       sum(net_discount) AS total_discount,
       SUM(CASE WHEN order_date BETWEEN DATEADD(dd,-10,GETDATE()) AND GETDATE() THEN net_amount ELSE 0 END)   AS total_spent10d,
       SUM(CASE WHEN order_date BETWEEN DATEADD(dd,-10,GETDATE()) AND GETDATE() THEN net_discount ELSE 0 END) AS total_discount10d,
       SUM(CASE WHEN order_date BETWEEN DATEADD(dd,-30,GETDATE()) AND GETDATE() THEN net_amount ELSE 0 END)   AS total_spent30d,
       SUM(CASE WHEN order_date BETWEEN DATEADD(dd,-30,GETDATE()) AND GETDATE() THEN net_discount ELSE 0 END) AS total_discount30d
FROM   [Order]
GROUP  BY customer_id;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a conditional aggregation approach so that in your "10d" and "30d" columns you only sum the values where the `order_date` meets your required condition.

e.g. something like the below

```
SELECT customer_id,
       sum(net_amount)   AS total_spent,
       sum(net_discount) AS total_discount,
       sum(IIF(order_date BETWEEN CAST(DATEADD(dd,-10,GETDATE()) AS date) AND CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) , net_amount  , 0))   AS total_spent10d,
       sum(IIF(order_date BETWEEN CAST(DATEADD(dd,-10,GETDATE()) AS date) AND CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) , net_discount, 0)) AS total_discount10d,
       sum(IIF(order_date BETWEEN CAST(DATEADD(dd,-30,GETDATE()) AS date) AND CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) , net_amount  , 0))   AS total_spent30d,
       sum(IIF(order_date BETWEEN CAST(DATEADD(dd,-30,GETDATE()) AS date) AND CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) , net_discount, 0)) AS total_discount30d
FROM   [Order]
GROUP  BY customer_id;
```

Comment: Ah sorry missed that

Comment: Hi @Martin, thank you for the wonderful code. This works perfectly with SQL. But when I use the same for dedicated SQL pool (synapse) which uses TSQL it throws error. Can you or someone help on this. Someone just edited my question and removed the 'TSQl' requirement from the header.

Comment: It is all TSQL for SQL Server. Dedicated SQL Pool  just uses a highly restricted subset of it. You should tag your questions `azure-synapse` as well. What is the error message? I'm not familiar with all its limitations. It may just not like the `IIF` in which case you can use `SUM(CASE WHEN order_date BETWEEN CAST(DATEADD(dd,-10,GETDATE()) AS date) AND CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) THEN net_amount ELSE 0 END)` instead.

Comment: @MartinSmith Your guess is absolutely correct and that works now. The case statement works fine with the dedicated SQL Pool. Thanks a lot for answering and replying with the updated query.